# I am unable to get the id and username in my json response in postman api

Tags: php, json

I am unable to get the id and username in the postman. i am getting like this output.{"status":true,"message":"Successfully Login!","id":"id","username":"username"}

```
<?php 
    include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/user.php';

$database = new Database ();
$db = $database -> getConnection();

$user = new User($db);
$user ->username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : die();
$user ->password = base64_encode(isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : die());

$stmt = $user ->login();

if($stmt ->rowCount() > 0){

    $row = $stmt ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => true,
        "message" => "Successfully Login!",
        "id" =>  $row['id'],
        "username" => $row['username']
    );
}
else{
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Invalid Username or Password!"
            );
}

print_r(json_encode($user_arr));
?>
```

my `login` function :

```
function login(){
   $query = "select 'id','username','password' from " . $this ->table_name . " where username ='".$this ->username."' and password='".$this ->password."'"; 
   $stmt = $this ->conn ->prepare($query);
   $stmt ->execute(); 
   return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: i have shared my code

Comment: What's inside. `$user->login()` function?

Comment: function login(){
  $query = "select 'id','username','password' from " . $this ->table_name . " where username ='".$this ->username."' and password='".$this ->password."'";
  $stmt = $this ->conn ->prepare($query);
  $stmt ->execute();
  return $stmt;
 }

Comment: Try `var_dump($row)` to see what is actually in there

Answer (score 0):

Your current query is

```
$query = "select 'id','username','password' from " . $this ->table_name . " where username ='".$this ->username."' and password='".$this ->password."'";
```

SQL will understand this as select the **values** *id, username and password*, not the **columns** *id, username and password*.
so if the query match, your return will always be

```
['id' => 'id', 'username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password']
```

Just remove the single quote around id, username, password, so your sql will become:

```
$query = "select id, username, password from " . $this ->table_name . " where username ='".$this ->username."' and password='".$this ->password."'";
```

Be aware that you are vulnerable to SQL injection by using string substitute directly to the sql command, please switch to prepare statement for better security.

Something like this

```
$query = "select id, username, password from " . $this ->table_name . " where username = :username' and password= :password";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query)
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $this->username, ':password' => $this->password));
```

Another issue is base64_encode is not the way to obscure user's password since it can be easily decoded, use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash) and [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify) to hash your password.